# Where has the command "mdcheckschema" been moved to in 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, spotlight

I'm working on a custom document mdimporter and trying to validate my schema.xml file. In the apple documentation they say to use "usr/bin/mdcheckschema" followed by the path to the file. It should return whether or not it was parsed successfully, but I just get "No such file or directory." To be clear if I just type the command, I receive the same thing, rather than terminal returning the manual for the command. I've tried "locate" and "whereis" and have only been able to find a single reference to it at "usr/share/man/man1/mdcheckschema.1" Has the command been moved or removed all together? The apple docs still suggest it should be in "usr/bin." I haven't had much luck finding this issue mentioned anywhere else.

This could probably be its own question, but in 10.8.2 "mdimport -L" doesn't return a list of all of the installed importers. Is this the case for anyone else?

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!  The executable seems to be missing in OS X 10.8.x although the `man` page for it is still there.  Of three 10.8 systems I've looked at, an older executable exists on one in `/usr/bin` but it is not known to be part of any installation package by `pkgutil` so I'm guessing it was left over from an upgrade from an earlier OS X.  A 10.7.5 system also does not have the executable but has the man page.  A 10.6.8 system *does* have it installed:

```
$ pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/mdcheckschema
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/mdcheckschema

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo
pkg-version: 1.0.0.9000000000.1.1248867338
install-time: 1328064907
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755
```

So it appears that it was at one time packaged as part of the Xcode Command Line Tools component ("Leo" would indicate OS X 10.5 Leopard).  I guess you'll have to ask Apple what has happened to it.  It could be just an oversight.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've posted the question to apple.discussions and the developer forum, so we'll see if someone there is able to resolve it. It's definitely making debugging my importer a lot more difficult.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  BTW, don't forget to accept answers that you find helpful to your questions here on StackOverflow.  That's how reputation building works, both for the questioner and the answerer.

Comment: Was there ever a respons regarding this on the Apple dev forums?

Comment: I filed a Radar for it, would suggest others to do the same.